# Redimensionar uma imagem antes de enviar para o Firebase

Tags: android, imagem, firebase

Eu quero redimensionar a imagem que está em imageView vinda de uma câmera ou galeria antes de enviar para o Firebase, como pode ver está sendo enviado o "filepath" que é uma uri assim não consigo utilizar o código scaleDown. Estou enviando a imagem para o storage do firebase e o link vai para database. Como posso fazer para redimensionar antes de enviar?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if ((requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST || requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
                filePath = data.getData();
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

            }
        }
    }
```

>

```
StorageReference sRef = storageReference.child(Constants.STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(filePath));

                //adding the file to reference
                sRef.putFile(filePath)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                //dismissing the progress dialog
                                progressDialog.dismiss();

                                //displaying success toast
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                //creating the upload object to store uploaded image details
                                Upload upload = new Upload(editTextName.getText().toString().trim(), editTextName1.getText().toString().trim(), editTextName2.getText().toString().trim(), taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());


                                String uploadId = mDatabase.push().getKey();
                                mDatabase.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);



                            }
                        })
```

ScaleImage

```
public static Bitmap scaleDown(Bitmap realImage, float maxImageSize, boolean filter) {
    float ratio = Math.min(
    (float) maxImageSize / realImage.getWidth(),
    (float) maxImageSize / realImage.getHeight());
    int width = Math.round((float) ratio * realImage.getWidth());
    int height = Math.round((float) ratio * realImage.getHeight());

    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage, width,height, filter);
    return newBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Poderia utilizar BitmapFactory:

```
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                        context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, BITMAP_MAX_SIZE, BITMAP_MAX_SIZE);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, options);

    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
```

Note que `BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, options);` com `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;`  te retornará `null` , mas terá `options.outWidth`e `options.outHeight` para poder calcular `options.inSampleSize` e então decodificar o bitmap novamente, mas aí sim com `options.options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;`

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: Como faria a implementação desse primeiro código, colocaria dentro do onActivityResult? mudaria o uri do openFileDescriptor(uri, "r"); para openFileDescriptor(filepath, "r");

Comment: Sim, seria dentro do onActivityResult ou num método a parte, como preferir. 
Mudaria openFileDescriptor(uri, "r") para openFileDescriptor(selectedImageUri, "r").
Creio que a ideia seja subir o bitmap para o firebase certo? Aí vc passaria o bitmap retornado para o storageReference

Comment: André, estou com problemas para implementar, o que seria RoundedBitmapDrawableUtil, é um método?, como implementar já que utilizei dois meios, câmera e galeria.

Comment: RoundedBitmapDrawableUtil seria a classe onde está o método calculateInSampleSize no meu projeto. Em ambos os casos em onActivityResult() o data.getData() te retorna a Uri.E então é só passar para o context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r"); (primeira linha do exemplo)

Comment: Desculpe André mas não estou entendendo, tens como editar meu código e mostrar como implementar o seu código? agradeço seu auxilio.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(
            requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
        ImageView img = (ImageView)
                findViewById(R.id.imageFoto);

        // Obtém o tamanho da ImageView
        int targetW = img.getWidth();
        int targetH = img.getHeight();

        // Obtém a largura e altura da foto
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions =
                new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                caminho_foto.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);

        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determina o fator de redimensionamento
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(
                photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

        // Decodifica o arquivo de imagem em
        // um Bitmap que preencherá a ImageView
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                caminhoDafoto.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```